# Paypal payment android

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying integrate paypal with my android application but I am getting and error `paypal android error_description":"Invalid client_id"`  As it clearly saying Client_id is invalid but I can't see any mistake I just copied from this page.
![enter image description here][1]

Code look like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button btnPay;
//set the environment for production/sandbox/no netowrk
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "nsdkjansdknaskd7415150U";

private static final int REQUEST_PAYPAL_PAYMENT = 1;

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
        // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
        .merchantName("Android Hub 4 You")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnPay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnPay.setOnClickListener(this);

    /**
     * call pay pal services
     */

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
    startService(intent);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1 :
         PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(1),"USD", "androidhub4you.com",
                    PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_PAYMENT); 
        break;
    }

}

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PAYPAL_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                        .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Responseeee"+confirm);
                        Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString());


                        JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(confirm.toJSONObject().toString());

                        String paymentId=jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
                        System.out.println("payment id:-=="+paymentId);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), paymentId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid Payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        } 


  }




  }
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that using PayPal in your App will violate the Google Play terms and conditions: https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: I am not going to publish it in googleplay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the correct credentials.  The 'App ID' that you are currently using are for the PayPal Adaptive Payment APIs and the legacy MPL.  For the Android mSDK, you'll need to follow the instructions [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/) to create a REST API app. This will show you how to create an App on the developer portal so that you are provided with a Client ID and secret.  This Client ID is what you need to use in the Android mSDK code you have above.